# log file error in in Raspberry with Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am use Python3 in my Raspberry Pi, and I have a code that someone has shared with me, the following line is shown to record the log file:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='/Desktop/var/log/morning/RER-execution-logs.txt',format='%(levelname)s:%(asctime)s:%(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
```

but when I tray to run the code using Python on my Raspberry I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 709, in <module>
main(sys.argv)
File "test.py", line 641, in main
logging.basicConfig(filename='/var/log/morning/RER-execution-logs.txt',format='%(levelname)s:%(asctime)s:%(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1900, in basicConfig
h = FileHandler(filename, mode)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1092, in __init__
StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1121, in _open
return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/log/morning/RER-execution-logs.txt'
```

I have also created the directory and the file manually but I get this other error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 709, in <module>
main(sys.argv)
File "test.py", line 641, in main
logging.basicConfig(filename='/var/log/morning/RER-execution-logs.txt',format='%(levelname)s:%(asctime)s:%(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1900, in basicConfig
h = FileHandler(filename, mode)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1092, in __init__
StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1121, in _open
return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/morning/RER-execution-logs.txt
```

what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply because the file that you are trying to log on **does not** actually exist. You could either create it manually, or use the below version of your Python script which will create it for you, if it does not exist already:

```python
import logging, os

logPath = '/Desktop/var/log/morning/RER-execution-logs.txt'

if not os.path.exists(logPath):
    open(logPath, 'w+').close()

logging.basicConfig(filename=logPath,format='%(levelname)s:%(asctime)s:%(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
```

However make sure that the path to that log file is actually correct. To be extra sure, use the absolute path. You are looking to something like:

`/home/pi/Destkop/...`